# PHP collect and combine different data from two tables

Tags: php, mysqli

I have these two tables which I'm trying to make an output of.
The first one `**USERS**` stores all information about a user, including an unique ID (androidID).
The second one gets input based on number of laps a user has taken, and will make one row pr lap.

What I'm trying to do is to output the last entry of a given androidID in `**ROUNDS**`, whith the corresponding name etc. from `**USERS**`

```
_____________________        _________________________
|    **USERS**      |        |      **ROUNDS**       |
---------------------        -------------------------
| NAME              |        | ID(unique)            |
| LASTNAME          |        | TIME                  |
| androidID(unique) | <----> | androidID(NOT unique) |
| ...               |        | ROUNDS                |
```

This is how I'm quering the server

```
$result_users = $con->query(
    "SELECT * FROM users"
);

$result_rounds = $con->query(
    "SELECT * FROM Rounds ORDER BY laps desc"
);
```

I tried to numerous  combination of the following. With no luck. My PHP skills is not the best, I'm afraid.

```
foreach ($result_users as $row_users) {
    foreach ($result_rounds as $row_rounds) {
         if($row_users['androidID'] == $row_rounds['androidID'] {
             // Do some wizzardy
         }
    }
}
```

I have really hit a wall trying to connect the tables.

Comment: What exact problem are you having? It never enters the if block? Have you tried debugging the values you are comparing?

Comment: Why select all rows from `Rounds`, when you can add a `WHERE Rounds.androidID = $row_users['androidID']`. Also, are we to assume `$con->query()` returns an assoc_array? Typically `->query()` is followed by a `->fetch_assoc_array()` or other method first.

Comment: Sorry, I should have been more clearer. My code do run in the inner loop. I have tested it with with simple `echo`s. The problem is that i really have no idea what to do with the data I'm collection. Say, how do I add this to an array in a way that I don't get redundancy. I'm only interested in the last entry of any `androidID` in `***ROUNDS**`,  with the corresponding name etc.. since this holds the latest update

Comment: If you only want the last row of each `androidID`, then instead of selecting all the rows, just the get last one -> `$result_rounds = $con->query("SELECT * FROM Rounds WHERE laps IN (SELECT MAX(laps) FROM Rounds GROUP BY androidID) ORDER BY androidID");`. The inner query gets all the last `laps` grouped by `androidID`. Then the outer query uses those to select the row info.

Comment: This is exactly the type of PHP wizardy I'm talking about. Thanks @Sean this did work. I can finally continue.

Comment: I always wonder why people put their answers in the comments... @Sean get yo points, son!

Comment: @JaredCobb It is because lately many OPs don't give enough info in the questions, so it takes many comments to figure out what they are really asking for. There are also a lot of anonymous down-voters on SO when you give only a partial answer while waiting for the OP to say `"that's not my actual code"` or `"that's not what I meant"`. Also, when you have new posters on here, with a rep of `1`, lately they never select an answer. So why go to the effort? I get my points as needed.

Comment: @Sean I know you are generalizing about users with low rep. Sometimes, as in my case, I realized, I didn't really know what I was asking, or more; how to ask. I have been staring at my computer for many hours, days on end, trying to write my thesis, and come up with a solution. I am, btw, somewhat active in the `tex`group. Even so, I'm glad you took the time to drag the "real" question out of me, and more for giving me what I needed to continue.

Comment: @DavidKristiansen please know that no offense was intended. I often fail to reread my comments to make sure the right tone/message is given. My intent was to share with @ JaredCobb (had to add space or SO gives error message that only 1 @ can be used) that the comments are useful in helping posters better clarify what they are trying to do, and it is not always about getting 'points'. I am glad I was able to help point you in the right direction, and wish you well on your thesis. Happy coding to you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would be the sql statement you want in your query.

```
SELECT * FROM `**USERS**` LEFT JOIN `**ROUNDS**`ON `**USERS**`.`androidID` = `**rounds**`.`androidID` ORDER BY `laps` desc 0,1;
```